# expressjs cookies aren't showing up in client

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, setcookie, express-jwt

I am using expressjs cookieParser to sign and make http only JWT cookies. I'm not getting any errors but the cookies aren't showing up on my Vite project or when I use Thunderclient to login then test a private route. It says req.cookies are '[Object: null prototype] {}'

```
              const AccessToken = generateAccessToken({
                username: user.username,
                email: user.email,
                id: user.id,
              });

              const RefreshToken = generateRefreshToken({
                username: user.username,
                email: user.email,
                id: user.id,
              });

              res
                .cookie("access_token", AccessToken, {
                  httpOnly: true,
                  secure: false,
                  sameSite: "none",
                  maxAge: 900000, // 15 min in milliseconds
                })
                .cookie("refresh_token", RefreshToken, {
                  httpOnly: true,
                  secure: false,
                  sameSite: "none",
                  maxAge: 86400000, // 1 day in milliseconds
                })
                .status(200)
                .json({
                  message: "Success login",
                  id: user.id,
                  email: user.email,
                  username: user.username,
                });
```

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry for the confusion. I mean when I console.log(req.cookies) it says that.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have a route in users to get the users current information. It should just be the payload of the JWT. It has middleware that checks the JWT before it is passed to the controller. It is there I am console.log'ing the cookies because I need to access them to verify the JWT before it is passed. router.get("/current", handleTokenValidation, currentUser);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256841/discussion-between-zach-philipp-and-jaromanda-x).